# Reading Mailbox or user nodes through iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, inbox, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

**Why this code gives error in fetching inbox**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me/inbox"
                              parameters:@{@"fields":@"inbox"}
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

**Error I get on console :**

```
{
    code = 100;
    message = "You can only access the \"inbox\" connection for the current user.";
}
```

**where as if If I use this code to fetch inbox it fetches me the inbox:**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request =[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                                          parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"inbox"}];
```

Comment: Figured out
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me/inbox?limit=50"
                                  parameters:nil//@{@"fields":@"data"}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out can not pass fields in param

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me/inbox?limit=50"
                              parameters:nil    
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```